# Localizing Windows Phone 8 'Application Title' and 'Tile Title' strings

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, localization

I have a simple Windows Phone 8 (WP8) app which I have localized by modifying AppResources.resx to create a version for Spanish.

Problem is the 'Application Title' and the 'Tile Title' on the WMAppManifest.xml are still in the default language (English).  I do not seem to be able to localize Application Title and Tile Title either through WMAppManifest.xml or AppResources.resx.

I have found and attempted to follow the instructions: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx

What I see are:
1. the WP8 applications lists as a file path '@C:\'.
2. The WP8 Application Title now shows as '@AppResLib.dll,-100'.
3. The WP8 Tile Title now shows as '@AppResLib.dll,-200'.

Clearly the values in WMAppManifest.xml for 'Application Title' and 'Tile Title' are not being interpreted.  Can I get them interpreted to the correct Localized values?

Is there another way or new guidance for WP8 (I have provided feedback to MS BTW)?

FYI, I have also reviewed the articles listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637522(v=vs.105).aspx

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: The url of Chris is identical to the first url in the question

Answer (score 7):

I had to place the AppResLib.dll.{lang}.mui in the root folder and not in "Resources" as asked by the MS tutorial. (Double check in the file properties that the Build Action is "content")

Comment: I wasted couple of hours to figure this out. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Looks like the original post has been edited to note the root folder as the site for the *.mui files.

Answer (score 3):

May I also suggest this tool: [WP7 AppResLib DLL Generator](http://engine-designs.com/2011/08/17/wp7-appreslib-dll-generator/). It will help you generate the localized dlls out of an XML file. This is especially useful if you are using the express edition of Visual Studio. The tool was initially built for WP7, but it is also working for WP8.

I would also like to raise your attention to this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/0d15fd18-b43e-40fa-b526-0ada65e7da9a/app-title-internationalization-not-shown-on-the-store-but-ok-on-the-tiles?forum=wpdevelop). You may experience the same issue that the localized app title appears correctly on the tiles, but on the store. The solution to this is to use specific language codes (en-US, de-DE) and completely avoid generic ones (en, de).

Answer (score 2):

I have followed the "How to localize an app title for Windows Phone", downloaded the "Language-Neutral Resource Project" and succeeded in localizing my app's title. Note: in "Language-Neutral Resource Project", you have to replace the "#include "afxres.h" by "#include "winnt.rh"", and delete all included libraries in "Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies". Good luck!