# Localizing App Name

Tags: c#, c++, dll, windows-phone-8, localization

Uff.. I am trying to localize the app name but i do not manage.

My solution has English language (NOT English USA and NOT English UK, just English) and a second language, that is the Italian Language (NOT Italian IT and NOT Italian Switzerland, just Italian). 
I can see this configuration on properties of my project and in WMAppManifest.xml (Packaging tab).

I have followed this guide

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx

In the end, i had this situation in my solution:

- AppResLib.dll in Solution folder, and with English Language;
- AppResLib.dll.0410.mui, in Resources Folder of my solution (Italian language).

It did not work... so i have looked for on web and I have found this page:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_solve_problems_localizing_the_app_name

So, now, i had this situation in my solution:

- AppResLib.dll in Solution folder, and with English Language;
- AppResLib.dll.0410.mui, in Resources Folder of my solution (Italian language).
- AppResLib.dll.0409.mui, in Resources Folder of my solution (English language).

It still does not work. My only doubt is that 0410 is for it-IT and 0409 is for en-US.

EDIT: I've tried to add the it-IT language support but nothing change.

EDIT: I've tried this solution but no result:

[Localizing Windows Phone 8 'Application Title' and 'Tile Title' strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689598/localizing-windows-phone-8-application-title-and-tile-title-strings)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved!

In the msdn guide, the point:

> "7. In Solution Explorer, move the AppResLib.dll.*.mui files into the Resources folder."

in the paragraph

> "Using the localized resource strings in your Windows Phone app"

is WRONG.

You do not must move anything. It must remain in the solution folder!