# Localize App Title For Windows Phone 8 Not Display Correctly

Tags: windows-phone-8

I looked up a couple questions on this and there were no real marked solutions so I figured I would ask it again.  I created an application for multiple languages.  I went through the link ,[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), created the main resource file and created all the other .mui files.  Basically did everything step by step.  Now when I test my application via the debugger all I get for the application title is @C:\Data\Programs{c and than it gets cut off.  The AppResLib.dll file is on the main root of the application.  The .mui files are in the Resources directory.  The Display Name and Tile Title have been changed to @AppResLib.dll, .   Any thoughts or possibly someone who ran into this issue before?

I also tried, [Localizing Windows Phone 8 'Application Title' and 'Tile Title' strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689598/localizing-windows-phone-8-application-title-and-tile-title-strings), but that didn't solve anything.  I used the winnt.rh instead and still get the @C:\Data\Programs{c.

Comment: Can you post some of your localization files? We might be able to see where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly set the values in `WMAppManifest.xml`?

`Title="@AppResLib.dll,-100"` for app title and `<Title>@AppResLib.dll,-101</Title>` for app tile title?

100 and 101 are the resource IDs from `AppResLib.rc`.

Comment: Yes.  I had them at 100 and 101 initially as the resource ID but the tutorial specified them as 100 and 200 so I switched them and that made no difference.  Not that I thought it would but figured I would cover all basis.

Comment: And which language are you trying to localize? What is the full name of your .mui file?

Comment: Various languages, including English which doesn't even work either.  One file name example is AppResLib.dll.0439.mui.

Comment: Have you tried placing the .dll and the .mui files in the root of the project (where the .csproj file is) instead of in the Resources folder? I had "C:\Data\Programs.." when I had my AppResLib.dll in Resources, then localization still didn't work until I moved all of the files in the project root.